# System won't boot up with new RAM sticks, nor with the old ones

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard

I bought new RAM sticks and put them in the proper slots. I cleaned the dust off the surface of the video card with a dry tissue and while at it attempted to vacuum the dust off the motherboard.

I then  powered on the system only to see it wouldn't boot up. I removed the new RAM sticks and put the old in, powered on again and again no signal transmitting to the monitor.

Before writing this post I’ve made one last check: with both the new and old sticks the monitor turns blue for a few seconds and then black. Is it safe to assume the motherboard was accidentally damaged?

Comment: Vacuum cleaner == massive static electricity potential.

Comment: I wouldn't immediately assume that you have "damaged" something.  Something to BLOW out the case is much better than trying to suck stuff out with a vacuum (as @Tetsujin points out).  Blow out the case.  Even a leaf blower will work in a pinch.  Pull and reseat everything you can.. if it doesn't work, try it again.  Don't admit defeat.. keep trying.  I doubt you actually damaged anything (howbeit possible).. you probably just unseated something.

Comment: Vacuum cleaner + case/cpu fan = generator. And if you have bad luck the "fan-generator" generates the wrong voltage or a voltage too high and damages components on the Mainboard.

Comment: Well, I have checked and re-checked, even before posting the question, all connectors are in place and RAM sticks well seated. At this point I think I've damaged some of the components.

Comment: I've managed to boot up the system, can't tell exactly what it was. The turning point was when I removed the cpu fan to check whether the cpu was in place, applied new thermal compound and booted again. The system magically entered into the BIOS. I found it odd, most likely some component was not properly seated.